# Custom static file provider is overridden by feature

Tags: .net-6.0, kestrel-http-server, asp.net-core-staticfile

I have registered a custom file provider as static file provider, but it seems to be overridden. I never get any calls to IFileInfo.CreateReadStream, but the files are still being served. The thing is I'm trying to add mem-caching for a few commonly read files, so I was implementing this in my custom file-info class on first read. But now it seems that this is overriden by IHttpSendFileFeature. This is not at all very clear. What is it that IHttpSendFileFeature does that is better than basic CreateReadStream+CopyTo? Is it implementing some kind of caching itself? Perhaps I shouldn't try add custom caching here at all. I'm not sure if file-caching is done elsewhere in the pipeline already, and perhaps much better? I'm using Kestrel on .NET 6.

I don't want to read these files from disk on every request since I'm running this on a server with mechanical discs. If I was running this with SSD's I guess I wouldn't have to worry that much about this, I mean since reads are so fast on SSD already. But also, I assume the OS do a bunch of file-paging/caching as well? So perhaps I should just skip all custom caching altogether?

Comment: `IHttpSendFileFeature` is obsolete and replaced by `IHttpResponseBodyFeature` the implementation can be seen here: https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/main/src/Http/Http/src/StreamResponseBodyFeature.cs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to remove the following

```
app.UseStaticFiles();
```

which calls

```
app.UseMiddleware<StaticFileMiddleware>();
```

If you remove `UseStaticFiles()` and instead call

```
app.UseMiddleware<MyStaticFileMiddleware>();
```

The original `StaticFileMiddleware` should no longer be called.

Your Post is a little unclear to me. How do you Serve those files?
The Services / Features you describe are not registered in the default service collection.

Comment: I serve them as you wrote, with StaticFileMiddleware. I don't register this feature manually so it seems that some other middleware perhaps registers it, if it's not default. The caching is only overridden when serving files with normal web-request and through the StaticFileMiddleware. When I invoke the file-provider myself server-side I get the caching. But your suggestion is a solution. I just wonder why it is like this, and also if caching of static files like this is unnecessary.

Comment: @AndreasZita In the default .NET 6 web app the static files are only requested once. Pressing F5 in the browser usually doesn't reload them. I would not bother caching static files on the server as the file system is usually faster than the traffic to your server. If your tests show that this is a problem i would recommend a custom middleware that serves the files. If you add a custom `StaticFileMiddleware` you can terminate the request early by not calling `next`, so whatever "other" StaticFileMiddleware is registered wont be called.

Comment: @AndreasZita If you really want to cache static files then maybe a RAM Disk would be a solution? The advantage would be that the ram disk would behave exactly like the file system out of the box, just much faster.